# jQuery if window width is less than 991px, make nav > li a unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap menu with submenu items. I have set the submenu items to hide by default when the screen size is less than 991px.

When the screen size is less than 991px, the custom mobile menu appears. I want the mobile menu anchor tags to show the submenu on click instead of going to their specified href location.

But when the submenu is showing, and the mobile menu anchor tag is clicked, I want the page to go to their specified href location.

This is my HTML:

```
               <nav id="navbar2" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                                <span class="menu-text">Menu</span>
                            </button>
                        </div><!-- end navbar-header -->


                        <!-- Syed Edit -->
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="responsive_nav"><div class="navbar-nav">

                            <ul class="nav"><li class=""><a href="/treatments/" target="_self" class="">Treatments</a><ul><li class=""><a href="/treatments/invisible-braces-invisalign/" target="_self" class="">Invisible braces (Invisalign)</a></li><li class=""><a href="/treatments/hidden-braces-lingual/" target="_self" class="">Hidden braces (Lingual)</a></li><li class=""><a href="/treatments/metal-braces-damon/" target="_self" class="">Metal braces (Damon)</a></li><li class=""><a href="/treatments/clear-tooth-coloured-braces-clarity/" target="_self" class="">Clear tooth coloured braces (Clarity)</a></li><li class=""><a href="/treatments/fast-treatment-6-months/" target="_self" class="">Fast treatment (6 months)</a></li><li class=""><a href="/treatments/the-treatment-process/" target="_self" class="">The treatment process</a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/about-us/" target="_self" class="">About us</a><ul><li class=""><a href="/about-us/why-choose-us/" target="_self" class="">Why Choose us?</a></li><li class=""><a href="/about-us/what-you-need-know-about-dr-preet/" target="_self" class="">What you need to know about Dr Preet</a></li><li class=""><a href="/about-us/in-the-press/" target="_self" class="">In the press</a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/meet-our-team/" target="_self" class="">Meet our team</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/" target="_self" class="">See the results</a><ul><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/invisalign/" target="_self" class="">Invisalign</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/damon-braces/" target="_self" class="">Damon braces</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/lingual-braces/" target="_self" class="">Lingual braces</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/fast-treatment-braces/" target="_self" class="">Fast treatment braces</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/fixed-metal-braces/" target="_self" class="">Fixed metal braces</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/self-ligating-braces/" target="_self" class="">Self-ligating braces</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/hidden-braces/" target="_self" class="">Hidden braces</a></li><li class=""><a href="/see-the-results/modern-fixed-braces/" target="_self" class="">Modern fixed braces</a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/cost/" target="_self" class="">Cost</a><ul><li class=""><a href="/cost/price-guide/" target="_self" class="">Price guide</a></li><li class=""><a href="/cost/finance-plans/" target="_self" class="">Finance plans</a></li></ul></li><li class=""><a href="/information-for-patients/" target="_self" class="">Information for patients</a><ul><li class=""><a href="/information-for-patients/caring-for-your-appliance/" target="_self" class="">Caring for your appliance</a></li><li class=""><a href="/information-for-patients/faqs/" target="_self" class="">FAQs</a></li><li class=""><a href="/information-for-patients/common-orthodontic-problems/" target="_self" class="">Common orthodontic problems</a></li></ul></li></ul>                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class=""><a href="/find-us/" target="_self" class="">Find us</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="/contact-us/" target="_self" class="">Contact us</a></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="/dentist-referrals/" target="_self" class="">Dentist referrals</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </div></div><!-- end navbar-collapse -->
                        <!-- Syed Edit -->


                    </nav><!-- end navbar -->
```

This is the CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-nav .nav li > ul {
        display: none!important;
    }
}
```

This is my attempt at doing this using jQuery:

```
  function(){
    $(".navbar-nav .nav li a").click(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".navbar-nav .nav li > ul").css("display","block");
        $(".navbar-nav .nav li > a").removeClass("disabled");
    }); 
});     

 $('.navbar-nav .nav > li a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
    return false; 
  else
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});

});

   $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 991) {
           $(".navbar-nav .nav li > a").addClass("disabled");
      }
     else {
           $(".navbar-nav .nav li > a").removeClass("disabled");
     }
    });
```

Comment: Rather than doing this with jQuery or the DOM, I would recommend having two main menus: One showing at 991+ and the other at <=991. Then the media queries just handle it.

Comment: i thought that too but the client does not want it done that way unfortunately, they want a single menu for both mobile and desktop.

Comment: That's strange. Same content, what's the difference?

Comment: Even better, remove the pointer for the link on small screens?

Comment: they're doing the menu using includes, and having one menu with submenus would be easier for them to modify in terms of submenu items etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .navbar-nav .nav > li a {
        pointer-events: none
    }
}
```

Explanation of what `pointer-events: none` does from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

Comment: This is by far the most user-friendly possible option.

Comment: This makes the anchor unclickable. But i want its child ul to be visible when this is clicked, which cannot happen when this is unclickable.

Comment: Do you want to target `.navbar-nav .nav li > ul`?

Comment: Also, please don't forget the mouse-free experience.  The anchors will still receive focus when tabbed to, and the href will still be invoked when the enter key is pressed.  The CSS pointer-events property is really meant to solve problems in a more graphic interface so that events can "pass through" an element, one that is being dragged over a target for example.